# Different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, string, performance, android-layout

I have looked through all of the android docs and many stack overflow questions, and I have a question on supporting multiple screen sizes. If I have some drawables, I know I need to put them in folders like these:

[image]

But does android make these folders for me? When I try copy and pasting my images into the drawable folder, I get something like this:

[image]

With no directory names. So do I have to manually make those directories, and then **will android automatically pick the right image to use depending on the screen size?**

I have the same question for the layout. For example, I know that to support many screen sizes, I need to put the layout in many folders like this:

[image]

But right now, my layout is like this:

[image]

So must I manually create each layout folder, and then copy and paste my current layout into the new layout folder, and then go into each layout, and render it until it looks nice on the android design tab of the XML? **Then, will android pick out the best layout depending on the screen size for me?**

I also get this when trying to make a new layout. What to fill in?

[image]
Thanks so much,

I have been delaying making my app compatible in different layouts because of these questions, I hope they can get answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create different layout folders and create layouts for standard screen sizes. There is a set of six generalized densities:

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

You can create images and layouts for these and use accordingly.Mention that in you manifest also:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />        
</compatible-screens>
```

Refer [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details

There are some tips :

1. Don't hard code any layout parameters such as width,height,etc..
2. Don't use "px".Use "sp" for font sizes and "dp" for layout-width, layout-height etc.
3. Make use of `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` and don't use `AbsoluteLayout` as it is deprecated.
4. Use `ScrollView` wherever required for layouts as it supports for a single view.

Comment: And android will pick which layout to use depending on screen size, right?

Comment: Yes. It will do that automatically if you do the above steps properly

Comment: Okay, so I have a layout named `activity_main.xml`. So what would the directory names be for the different densities you mentioned?

Comment: You have to use the same name `activity_main.xml` for this layout in all folders. Then only android will know that these are same

Comment: So something like `activity_main-ldpi` as one directory name? The reason I'm asking is because in the other answer, by sud, he mentions to use something like `activity_main-sw480dp`...which I don't know what means much. The android docs say that the `ldpi, mdpi, hdpi...etc.` are deprecated, and that I should use `sw<>dp` instead. It also indicates that the number is the minimum width...This seems a lot more confusing. Should I just use the deprecated directories? If not, how do I use the `sw<>dp` directory? Thanks

Comment: Oh. No. Not the directory name! Directory names should be `ldpi, mdpi, hdpi,...` for images and same as your screenshot for layouts.

Comment: Then what is the `sw<>dp` thing that is on the android docs. Also, sud mentions it, so I am confused on which one to use. Should I name my directory something like `layout-sw480dp` like sud said, or like `layout-small` like you said?

Comment: Refer https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/

Comment: Do I have to mention in manifest? Will my app show up in the "available for tablets" section if I do?

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to make different layout folders for different screen sizes like `layout-sw480dp` ,`layout-sw600dp` like that for different screen sizes and for landscape view use `layout-landscape`. and you have to use`drawable-hdpi` ,`drawable-mdpi`,`drawable-ldpi` ,`drawable-xhdpi` etc to put different resoultion images for different screeen resolution devices

Comment: For landscape view, if I make another folder saying `layout-landscape` and put my layout in, when the phone is turned to landscape, that layout will display? Also,android will pick which layout to use depending on screen size, right?

Comment: yes if you create `layout-landscape` then when phone rotated your layout from this folder will load

Comment: Also,android will pick which layout to use depending on screen size, right?  -yes right it will choose depending upon screen size say for small screen it will go for `layout` folder and for medium screen `layout-sw480dp` and so on

Comment: Alright, thanks. I have another question. So should I use `layout-normal, layout-large, layout-small...etc.` or should I use something like `layout-sw480dp`? Because in the other answer posted, Jas suggests to use the normal, large, small stuff, so what to do?

Comment: no not like this-layout-normal, layout-large, layout-small...etc.... use  layout-sw480dp , layout-sw600dp etc

Comment: actually it is not wrong you can use that , but in general practice i have seen like layout-sw480dp etc .. see [this] (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96630/discussion-between-nullpointerexception-and-sud).